# Regex for user login verification

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use regex to check if a user name is considered valid. For a user name to be valid it must be between 2 and 10 characters long. It must start with a lower case letter and it must be made up of only lowercase letters, upper case letters or digits.

Here is what I have so far

```
return preg_match("/^[a-z]([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,10})$/", $name);
```

Comment: Should probably be `{1,9}`, because you've already consumed the first letter.

Comment: sorry the 3 and 8 were old values I was messing with I meant to do 2 and 10 I will try 1 and 9 though

Comment: You have to be careful since this expression will match 'iddhartha' in the name 'Siddhartha'. You need to match whole words, perhaps try catching for a space before and after the name?

Comment: Hey Thanks!!! changing the bounds is all it took to get it working.

Comment: Have a look at this modified example: http://regex101.com/r/fX9sG9

Comment: Cool that looks good. That seems like a cool website I am going to check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For consistency, your capture expression should include your whole username (in your case you are skipping the first letter). You've also noticed you only need to use `{1,9}` for the second half:

```
^([a-z]{1}[a-zA-Z\d]{1,9})$
```

- this is matching **one** lowercase letter to begin with, followed by between 1 and 9 `a-zA-Z0-9`s afterwards, and capturing the whole username.

Modifiers (if required): `mg` (multi-line, match-all [for when testing with a block of multiple lines])

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/qW6kN5